# How to combine tabs and navbar in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to create next structure for my app settings screen header:

```
|<-  Settings     |
|-----------------|
| Tab 1  |  Tab 2 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|   Active tab    |
|    content      |
|                 |
|                 |
```

I tried to do that:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <RouterWithRedux>
        <Scene key="root">
            <Scene key="landing" component={Landing} title="Landing" initial={true} />
            <Scene tabs key="rootTabBar" back wrap={false} title="Settings">
                <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" icon={TabIcon} initial />
                <Scene key="search" component={Search} title="Search" icon={TabIcon} />
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
    </RouterWithRedux>
</Provider>
```

but I get not what I expected, [on attached screen is wrong tabs names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Govsl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
 <Scene key="root" hideNavBar headerStyle={{ marginTop:STATUSBAR_HEIGHT, elevation:0}} >

            <Scene key="main" hideNavBar >

                <Scene key="newsList"
                    tabs={true}
                    hideNavBar={false}
                    headerMode='none'
                    navBar={Header}
                    wrap={false}

                >
                    <Scene key="TehcList" component={TehcList} title="Teknoloji" />
                    <Scene key="GameList" component={GameList} title="Oyun" />
                </Scene>

            </Scene>
        </Scene>
```

Comment: This should definitely be the right answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import {Router, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Post from './screens/Post';
import Forum from './screens/Forum';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
       <Scene key = "root">
          <Scene key = "main" 
                tabs={true} 
                hideNavBar={true} 
                tabBarStyle={styles.navigationTabBar} 
                hideBackImage={true}>  
                    <Scene key = "home" component = {Home} title = "Home" initial={true} hideNavBar = {true}/>
                    <Scene key = "post" component = {Post} title = "Post" hideNavBar = {true} />
                    <Scene key = "forum" component = {Forum} title = "Forum" hideNavBar = {true} />
          </Scene>
       </Scene>
    </Router>
 )

 export default Routes
```

Got clue from http://pythonic.ninja/how-to-navigate-to-nested-tab-using-react-native-router-flux.html`